# Reinitializing numbers in file (with differing amounts of columns?)

Tags: python

I have a file that looks as so:

```
#name   chrom   exonStarts  exonEnds
NM_005101   chr1    948846,949363,  948956,949919,
NM_198576   chr1    955502,957580,970656,976044,976552,976857,977335,978618,978917,979202,979488,979713,980540,980738,981112,981343,981539,981776,982199,982706,982952,983155,983391,984246,984615,984945,985282,985612,985806,986105,986632,986832,987107,989132,989827,990203,    955753,957842,970704,976260,976777,977082,977542,978837,979112,979403,979637,979819,980657,980903,981256,981468,981645,982115,982337,982834,983067,983275,983745,984439,984831,985175,985417,985709,985971,986217,986749,987025,987195,989357,989931,991499,
NM_003327   chr1    1146705,1147083,1147321,1148017,1148371,1149042,1149362,    1147005,1147212,1147518,1148084,1148473,1149165,1149548,
```

What I want to do is subtract the number first number in column 3 from the rest of the numbers from that value on. For example, this is what I would want my output to be for line one:

```
NM_005101   chr1    1,110,    517,1073,
```

I originally decided to split my file by the `,` but that resulted in a differing amount of columns for each line, making it difficult. My ultimate goal is to somehow figure out a way to add these values to a dictionary with the name as the key and the values (exonStart and exonEnds) to be a list of ranges so I can test from a second file if a certain value is in a particular range given the name and position.

Example of my final dictionary:

```
posdic = {name:[[start, end], [start, end]], name: etc}
```

Is the best approach to split my file by `,` and try to figure out a way to subtract the first value from the rest of columns even though the lines are of differing lengths?

Comment: `1,110` should actually be `0,110`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a function that processes one line in the format you specified:

```
def read_exons(line):
    parts = iter(line.split())
    name = next(parts)
    chrom = next(parts)
    starts = map(int, next(parts).strip(',').split(','))
    ends = map(int, next(parts).strip(',').split(','))
    base = starts[0]
    return name, [(s-base, e-base) for s, e in zip(starts, ends)]
```

It returns a tuple containing the name and a list of start/end pairs:

```
>>> read_exons('NM_005101   chr1    948846,949363,  948956,949919,')
('NM_005101', [(0, 110), (517, 1073)])
```

You can process a whole file as follows. Note that the `dict` constructor takes a sequence of tuples, as they are returned by `read_exons`, to be used as key/value pairs:

```
>>> with open('input.txt') as f: # use the real filename
...     exons = dict(read_exons(line) for line in f
...                  if not line.strip().startswith('#'))
>>> exons.keys()
['NM_005101', 'NM_198576', 'NM_003327']
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you. I would have never thought to define a function since I haven't done it often (new to python/programming). I wonder if there is a way to carry out the creation of this dictionary in an alternative way. It would probably just be longer and less efficient.

Comment: You can read more about it in the official [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). If you use Python version 2.7 or newer, you could perhaps use a *dict comprehension*, but I think it would get more complicated that way.

Answer (score 0):

if you allways have that space char between the exonStarts and the exonEnds you can split by the space char and then split each string in the array by ','
if not you should try put a special char between each column so that you will be able to split by it.